# Segmentation fault (core dumped) in ubuntu 12.04 yylex() call

Tags: c, ubuntu, segmentation-fault, flex-lexer, lex

The code below is trying to concatenate two text files and the output is written to another text file. As it's seen, I use `yylex()` function to get the tokens from the input files. The `yywrap()` function helps me to pass from the 1st text file to the 2nd text file and signals when EOF (End-Of-File) has been reached.
Why am I getting the error `"Segmentation fault (core dumped)"` on my laptop, while on my colleague's it works properly?
I mention that I am using the terminal as root.
This is how I use the commands:

```
::-:lex tokdef.l
::-:cc lex.yy.c -o dan -ll
::-:./dan 1text 2text outtext
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

And this is my code:

```
%{
    #include<string.h>
    int second_file = 0;
    char *nume2;
%}
%%
.;
\n;
%%
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    nume2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(argv[2])+1));
    strcpy(nume2, argv[2]);
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    yyout = fopen(argv[3], "w");
    yylex();
    fclose(yyin);
    fclose(yyout);
}
int yywrap()
{
    if(second_file == 0)
    {
        fclose(yyin);
        yyin = fopen(nume2,"r");
        second_file = 1;
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have two `fclose(yyin)` calls? and also why are you using the terminal as root for this?

Comment: @iharob the first `fclose(yyin)` is for the 1st file and the second is obviously for the 2nd file. If I do not use terminal as root `lex.yy.c` file connot be created.

Comment: As a regular user I get the same error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figure it out what was the problem. So it doesn't matter how do I use the terminal (root or regular). The problem was linked to the input files (1text and 2text). Firstly, I created the 1text and to create the 2text, file I just copied and paste the `1text` file and rename it as `2text`. So, my next question: What happens when I copy and paste a file in the same folder?

Comment: I think have the answer for this too: when you copy and paste a file, both have the same inode on the hard disk, so this could be the root of the problem.